# Python: partition list of names into equally sized sublists

Tags: python, group-by

I have a list of names, e.g. `['Agrajag', 'Colin', 'Deep Thought', ... , 'Zaphod Beeblebrox', 'Zarquon']`. Now I want to partition this list into approximately equally sized sublists, so that the boundaries of the subgroups are at the first letter of the names, e.g A-F, G-L, M-P, Q-Z, not A-Fe, Fi-Mo, Mu-Pra, Pre-Z.

I could only come up with a statically sized parition that doesn't take size of the subgroups into account:

```
import string, itertools

def _group_by_alphabet_key(elem):
    char = elem[0].upper()
    i = string.ascii_uppercase.index(char)
    if i > 19:
        to_c = string.ascii_uppercase[-1];
        from_c = string.ascii_uppercase[20]
    else:
        from_c = string.ascii_uppercase[i/5*5]
        to_c = string.ascii_uppercase[i/5*5 + 4]
    return "%s - %s" % (from_c, to_c)

subgroups = itertools.groupby(name_list, _group_by_alphabet_key)
```

Any better ideas?

P.S.: this may sound somewhat like homework, but it actually is for a webpage where members should be displayed in 5-10 tabs of equally sized groups.

Comment: It seems to me like there are multiple problems here: deciding where to split, and then splitting. The actual splitting is easy once you have split positions, so let's focus on that. The decision of where to split requires rules, that need to be figured out before the code can be written. For example, is it ever acceptable to put names starting with different letters into different partitions? If so, under what conditions? If not, then it seems like a simple matter of seeing how many names start with each letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something that might work. I feel certain there's a simpler way though... probably involving `itertools`. Note that `num_pages` only roughly determines how many pages you'll actually get.

EDIT: Whoops! There was a bug -- it was cutting off the last group! The below should be fixed, but note that the length of the last page will be slightly unpredictable. Also, I added `.upper()` to account for possible lowercase names.

EDIT2: The previous method of defining letter_groups was inefficient; the below dict-based code is more scalable:

```
names = ['Agrajag', 'Colin', 'Deep Thought', 'Ford Prefect' , 'Zaphod Beeblebrox', 'Zarquon']
num_pages = 3

def group_names(names, num_pages):
    letter_groups = defaultdict(list)
    for name in names: letter_groups[name[0].upper()].append(name)
    letter_groups = [letter_groups[key] for key in sorted(letter_groups.keys())]
    current_group = []
    page_groups = []
    group_size = len(names) / num_pages
    for group in letter_groups:
        current_group.extend(group)
        if len(current_group) > group_size:
            page_groups.append(current_group)
            current_group = []
    if current_group: page_groups.append(current_group)

    return page_groups

print group_names(names, num_pages)
```

Comment: That seems to work reasonably well with my real data of about 500 Names. Thanks!

Comment: @piquadrat, thanks for accepting -- but note the bug! It's fixed above.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `name_list` has to be sorted for `groupby` to work, can't you just check every Nth value and build your divisions that way?

```
right_endpoints = name_list[N-1::N]
```

And using `"A"` as your leftmost endpoint and `"Z"` as your rightmost endpoint, you can construct the N divisions accordingly and they should all have the same size.

1. So, the first left endpoint would be "A", the first right endpoint would be `right_endpoints[0]`.
2. The next left endpoint would be the character after `right_endpoints[0]`, the next right endpoint would be `right_endpoints[1]`.
3. Etc., until you hit the Nth range and that has a set endpoint of "Z".

The issue you may run into is what if two of these `right_endpoints` are the same...

**edit:** example

```
>>> names = ['Aaron', 'Abel', 'Cain', 'Daniel', 'Darius', 'David', 'Ellen', 'Gary', 'James', 'Jared', 'John', 'Joseph', 'Lawrence', 'Michael', 'Nicholas', 'Terry', 'Victor', 'Zulu']
>>> right_ends, left_ends = names[2::3], names[3::3]
>>> left_ends = ['A'] + left_ends
>>> left_ends, right_ends
>>> ["%s - %s" % (left, right) for left, right in zip(left_ends, right_ends)]
['A - Cain', 'Daniel - David', 'Ellen - James', 'Jared - Joseph', 'Lawrence - Nicholas', 'Terry - Zulu']
```

Comment: But he wants to divide at initial character boundaries, not just anywhere.

Comment: Right, the initial character extraction is left out to simplify, but the idea is still the same.  Get every Nth entry, extract what you want as an endpoint-definer out of it, and go from there.